# How do you display a list of numbers using a for loop and one int variable?

Tags: python

How do you create a display of a list of variables, stemming from one number, all while using a for loop?

Here is what I am thinking of:

```
Hours = 6    
for x in Hours():
    Print(x <= Hours)

# This is obviously wrong
```

The answer:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `range` function with a step of -1

In your case: `range(6,0,-1)`

```
for i in range(6, 0, -1):
    print(i)
```

Explication of the range function: https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

Answer (score 1):

Use this one-liner:

`print('\n'.join([str(i) for i in range(6, 0, -1)]))`

This gets a list of integers from 6 to 0 (excluding zero), stepping backwards by one, takes a string of each int `str(i)` and `joins` these with newlines `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative one line answer:

`[print(x) for x in range(6, 0, -1)]`